# Resharper surround class with region by code cleanup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

C#, VS2010, Resharper 8.

How can I surround class with region (containing class name) by code cleanup?

I wrote custom cleanup pattern, works fine, except this moment.

Does this mean, that cleanup pattern works only inside class? Is there any other way to do this automatically? Is there other way to extend code cleanup?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're trying to ADD regions? Generally, the need for regions is considered a smell that you have too much code in a single class or file.

Comment: Yes:( There is damn reason - code style in our company:( I tried to understand, discuss, ask colleagues:( There is no rational reason other than a mandatory requirement

Comment: Unfortunately, ReSharper 8.1 does not support surrounding top classes in file with regions - http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-47241. But as I see, it will be possible in ReSharper 9.0 release.

Comment: May be other way? Without resharper?